# How to set host_name() value in a Sql Server Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have existing triggers which read the workstation id property of the connection string using host_name().   There are existing PowerBuilder client applications connecting to the database directly and this setting was used to pass the identity of the current user to the application (not my design).

We have newer web applications updating the database, and the triggers require the user identity information to be present in host_name.  However, we don't want to set the user id in the connection string due to the affect on connection pooling (connections are not pooled across all users).

We pass the identity of the user via stored procedure parameters and would like to somehow set the host_name in the stored procedure such that the trigger requirements are satisfied.

How might this be accomplished, if at all?

Comment: Hopefully you can't spoof the hostname inside of SQL Server - it's bad enough this is allowed from the application layer. Change your triggers.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you can.  At least if you are connecting through SSMS you can. Still better to change the triggers though.  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/01/09/sql-server-how-to-hide-yourself-from-sql-server-guest-post-by-balmukund-lakhani/

Comment: @Kenneth But that's done outside of the database - the OP is using PowerBuilder (not SSMS) and doesn't want to fudge this from the connection string (which is what SSMS is doing too). SSMS and PowerBuilder are both "the application layer" that I'm talking about. The OP seems to want to be able to `SET @@HOSTNAME = foo` in T-SQL.

Comment: I cannot change the triggers.  I am limited to doing something to set Host_Name inside the stored procs for my application, as noted by by @AaronBertrand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't manipulate `HOST_NAME()` inside of SQL Server. And I think that's a good thing. The fact that you can spoof this in the connection string is something I've long considered a security problem waiting to happen.

Instead, you will need to change the logic in your triggers. For example you could store `HOST_NAME()` in a variable, then check `PROGRAM_NAME()` - if it's your PowerBuilder app, overwrite the variable with whatever, and then the trigger logic can check the variable instead of `HOST_NAME()`.

(You can do that in fewer steps, obviously; just illustrating.)

Comment: Changing it on the client may not be a good thing, but it can be done already so the train has left the station on that.   Therefore, changing it on the server would be no worse at this point.  I am unable to change the triggers at this point however.

Comment: @Richard then you'll have to change it on the client (have you actually tested the impact to connection pooling that you're afraid of?)

Comment: We have tested it.  Oh well.  Some things are just beyond my control.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SET CONTEXT_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx) and [CONTEXT_INFO()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx). This lets you set and retrieve 128 bytes of connection-specific metadata (as a varbinary(128) value).

So, after the connection is opened, you can do this:

```
DECLARE @ci varbinary(128) = CAST('myhostname.domain.com' AS varbinary(128))
SET CONTEXT_INFO @ci
```

Then in your triggers, you can see if the value has been set, and override `HOST_NAME()` as appropriate:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS varchar(128)), HOST_NAME())
```

It's not totally seamless, since you'll have to modify the trigger logic, but it's a start at least.

Comment: I cannot change the existing triggers.